# Unable to run phpMyAdmin in AWS Server

Tags: amazon-web-services, phpmyadmin, mariadb

I am working on AWS Server and right now i am trying to open "Phpmyadmin" but not wokring (showing me home page instead of phpmyadmin),I used "ls" command and i am getting following files/foder ( directory)

```
Arabic                      hooks           package-lock.json  README.md
components                  next.config.js  pages              styles
final-firstVersion          node_modules    phpMyAdmin         utils
final-firstVersion (1).zip  package.json    public             yarn.lock
```

then i tried with following command for run "phpMyAdmin"

```
sudo systemctl status mariadb
```

So as we can see there is "phpMyAdmin" folder but whenever i use "http://domainname/phpMyAdmin" then unable to open "database",How can i fix this ?

Comment: Ideas [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19127/how-to-access-phpmyadmin-after-installation). Also, check for case sensitivity - should it be /phpMyAdmin or /phpmyadmin?

Comment: Could you specify what kind of server you're running in AWS (Are you using EC2, ECS, AppRunner, LightSail, ...) and how have you configured your server: e.g. which OS and runtimes are installed and if there's for example an Apache or Nginx configured, sharing those configurations might reveal important information.

It would also be helpful to mention if the server works otherwise (responds to other http requests, is able to execute other php scripts in this described folder structure, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

MariaDB is the MySQL server, phpMyAdmin is a web interface that allows you to connect to MySQL databases, and phpMyAdmin requires Webserver i.e Apache, Nginx in addition to PHP handler

I found a useful article for you on how to setup phpMyadmin under Amazon Linux

https://jumpcloud.com/blog/how-to-install-phpmyadmin-amazon-linux-2